# Does the Windows Timeline Feature for Windows work with all apps and programs?

Tags: windows, windows-10, multitasking

I have heard in the past that Windows Timeline mainly only worked for Windows applications made by Microsoft or applications that integrated that timeline functionality into their apps.

I just want to know if that is still the case.

Are there some apps and programs that don't work in Windows Timeline in the most recent versions of Windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

Windows Timeline only works for applications whose developers added support for
[Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph).

This includes mainly Microsoft products at the moment.

For syncing to the cloud in order to be accessed on other devices, this requires
login with the same Microsoft account of Windows or the concerned applications.

Comment: Acrobat is supported but not a Microsoft product and neither is SnagIt, so I have zero Idea of why would downvote an additional good answer,